# Return value in header of an HTTP call(POST)

Tags: c#, .net, http, post

I'm making a call in my API using Postman that returns me this:

[PostMan Return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmP5P.png)

the system get this value from this abstract class:

```
public abstract class ResponseBase
{
   public long SessionId { get; set; }
}
```

After to get the property value, falls into this method in class `BasicAuthHttpModule`:

```
private static void OnApplicationEndRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
    //response.AddHeader("SessionId", )
    if (response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
        response.Headers.Add("WWW-Authenticate",
            string.Format("Basic realm=\"{0}\"", Realm));
    }
}
```

I want to pass the value to a `Header` in my response, but i don't know where is the value in `OnApplicationEndRequest`.

It is possible to see de SessionId value in debug mode, inside `OnApplicationEndRequest`?

Comment: Can you post your api calling code here.

Comment: I edited the question to try to make it clearer @NaveenKN